# Is there any way to increment specific field by fixed number without writing custom SMTs in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Let's assume that I have a table 'student' like below and use Debezium MySQL source connector and JDBC sink connector.

| id | class_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'Alice' | 15 |
| 2 | 1 | 'Bob' | 16 |
| 3 | 2 | 'Charlie' | 15 |

When I CDC this table, I just want 'id' and 'class_id' column to be incremented by 1 billion.

The high level architecture diagram to CDC(Change Data Capture) would be like below.

> DB1(MySQL) -> MySQL source connector(Debezium) -> Kafka -> (Unwrap SMT) -> (RegexRouter SMT) -> JDBC sink connector -> (?) -> DB2(MySQL)

- Unwrap SMT is for transforming Debezium change event format to be compatible with JDBC sink connector
- RegexRouter SMT is for changing topic name to be the target table I want it to be sync to
- I'm just thinking to place specific SMT(s) to increment 1 billion on specific fields(which is columns) I want.

Would it be any out-of-the-box SMT(s) to be placed on '(?)' part to achieve it, or should I just implement custom SMT?

Comment: "I just want 'id' and 'class_id' column to be incremented by 1 billion." Can you elaborate on why you're doing this? It might be there's a better way to achieve what you're doing, depending on what it is that you're doing :)

Comment: I'm going to migrate rows in a DB to another DB in realtime with CDC. They use their own auto increment, so there are PK conflicts. So I'm going to avoid this situation by incrementing specific number on migration pipeline. Would there be better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in Kafka Streams,. Or use ksqlDB or other stream processing framework. Otherwise, if you need data manipulated before written to Kafka that doesn't match a builtin transform, you'll need your own

Comment: I've already decided to use Kafka Connect because I just don't want to deploy and manage standalone application only for it and I prefer a way without writing codes if possible. Also, there is no ksqlDB cluster, but kafka connect cluster already in our company infrastructure. That's the reason why I asked the way with Kafka Connect and SMTs.

Comment: You'll need to write code for this. Otherwise, I've seen some JSONPatch or Groovy transformer on github, I think

Comment: What you've seen are these? https://github.com/willhaben/wh-kafka-connect-jslt-transform, https://github.com/Sergey34/kafka-connect-transformers

Comment: I think there's another Groovy one that I think was mentioned in Debezium blog once, but yes, something like those